# Running time of calculating x^y

Tags: algorithm, big-o, performance

How do I go about finding the running time (in Big-O notation) of the basic algorithm that performs `(y − 1)` multiplications by `x` to find `x^y`?

Edit: I also need to keep in mind the running time of each multiplication: "assuming that the time to multiply an `n-bit` number by an `m-bit` number is `O(mn)`".

Comment: Err .. if one multiplication is one operation ...

Comment: I've added a note to the question saying that each multiplication is not one operation, but has it's own running time as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: There are better alogirthms for power, with `O(log(y))` multipications. Sure you don't need this one?

Comment: @ruslik: This is a homework problem, so I don't really get to choose :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you just have to consider the number of bits for each operation and sum them up.  Of course we'll do a little rounding in order to simply things since it won't affect the big-O notation answer.

So, the number of bits in x is ceiling(log2(x)) (i.e. the next integer above the logarithm base 2 of x).  We will call this number b, for simplicity.  This means that x is bigger than 2^(b-1) and smaller than 2^b.  So x^2 is bigger than 2^(2(b-1)) and smaller than 2^(2b).  As such, we're going to assume that x^2 is of size approximately 2b, and that in general, x^n is of size nb.  This is pretty close to correct since it lies between n(b-1) and nb.

Our first multiplication will take time b*b = b^2.  Our second multiplication will take 2b*b (since x^2 has size 2b and x is still size b).  Our third will be 3b*b (since x^3 has size 3b and x is still size b).  So, in general, our nth multiplication will be nb*b.

So our sum looks like b^2 + 2b^2 + 3b^2 + ... + (y-1)b^2.  We can factor out b^2, giving us (b^2)(1+2+3+...+(y-1)).  For the second term, 1+2+3+...+(y-1) we can use a common formula that 1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2.  So we get (b^2)(y-1)(y)/2.

At this point we're very close to the answer, but we want to do two things: we want to express everything in terms of x and y (and not b) and we want to reduce things using big-O notation for simplicity.  (y-1)(y)/2 can be simplified to O(y^2).  b = ceiling(log2(x)), which can be simplified to O(log(x)).  Substituting back in, we get **O( (log(x))^2 * y^2 )**.

All this is, of course, assuming that we're using an algorithm which looks like this:

```
product = 1
for i = 1 to y
  product = product * x
return product
```

If we're doing something more complex and strange like this one:

```
xs = empty list
for i = 1 to y
  xs.addItem(x)
while xs is not empty
  num1 = xs.removeRandomItem
  num2 = xs.removeRandomItem
  xs.addItem(num1*num2)
return head(xs)
```

then the timing analysis gets way more complex.  (Note that this algorithm also does y-1 multiplications and gets the correct result.)

The other common algorithm for finding x^y is the repeated squaring algorithm which works like this:

```
result = 1
temp = x
while y>0
  if y mod 2 = 1
    result = result * temp
    y = y - 1
  temp = temp * temp
  y = y / 2
return result
```

For that one we do two multiplications each round which involve two numbers, each of which are size b(2^n) where n is the round number counting from 0 (that is, the number of times we've been through the while loop).  So in round n, each multiplication would cost b(2^n)*b(2^n)=(b^2)(2^(2n)).  But it only goes ceiling(log2(y)) rounds.  So its running time would be the sum of (b^2)(2^0)+(b^2)(2^2)+(b^2)(2^4)+...+(b^2)(2^(2*ceiling(log2(y)))).  So again we can factor out b^2 leaving (b^2)(2^0+2^2+2^4+...+2^(2*ceiling(log2(y)))).  Despite looking complicated, the whole second term is actually O(y^2).  Once we again substitute for b, we find that this one is also O((log(x))^2 * y^2).  So, although this algorithm is faster when multiplications are constant time operations, it's not necessarily faster when we're working with BigIntegers or other arbitrary precision types.  This is why it's most commonly used with situations like matrix multiplication where the cost of doing a multiplication is constant but large.

Comment: Perfect, after a lot of thinking, I arrived at the same answer yesterday. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

O(logy) or O(y) depending on the method you chose, you should start reading this http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.4

In your case for (y-1) multiplications O(y) number of steps, assuming a multiplication is one operation, because doubling the size of y will result in doubling the amount of operations needed this is called a linear process.

LE: in that case you will have 1*n^2 + 2*n^2 + ... + y*n^2. The first time you multiply the number by itself hence n*n = n^2 the second time the result n*n (size 2n) by the number n => 2n^2 and so on.

n^2 ( 1+2+...y) = n^2*y*(y+1)/2

So the answer is O(n^2*y^2) where n = number of bits in x ( or n = ceil(log(x))).

Comment: The question clearly stated that the algorithm performs `y - 1` multiplications.

Comment: Don't understand downvoting this. I'm upvoting, not because the answer is particularly informative (very difficult considering the question), but because it doesn't deserve a negative status

Comment: Are you saying that n is the length of x?

Comment: @nvm: Wouldn't you get 2n for the first time you multiply the number by itself, since the length of the number would be doubled?

Comment: @Chetan: you stated that <<I also need to keep in mind the running time of each multiplication: "assuming that the time to multiply an n-bit number by an m-bit number is O(mn)".>>  Considering your assumptions this is the result.

Comment: I assumed that O(mn) actually means O(m*n)

Comment: @nvm:This answer is quite simply wrong. Your initial sum is not set up correctly. The first term 1*n^2 is correct, but after that, you have a 2n bit number and an n bit number. Their product will take time 2n*n = 2*n^2, not 1*n^3. Likewise, the next term should be 3n*n = 3*n^2, not 1*n^4. As a result, your final conclusion is incorrect. This should also be obvious from a simple sanity check. Even if every multiplication was between two numbers of the size x^y (which is n*y bits), then we'd be looking at time y*(n*y)*(n*y) = O(n^2*y^3). Your answer of O(n^y) is way, way, way bigger than that.

Comment: @nvm: Much more accurate now that you've fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

If each multiplication is counted as a single operation, then an algorithm requiring `y - 1` steps is simply `O(y - 1) = O(y)`, which is the most common answer you'll find for this question. In reality, multiplication cannot be done in constant time so you'll need to multiply by the speed of whatever [multiplication algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm) you're using.

Note that by using [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), you can do fewer than `y - 1` operations and your exponentiation algorithm can be `O(log y)` instead.